# Weak lower semi continuity weakly sequentially closed

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-optimization

Let X be a Banach space and $J:X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$
a functional. Show that J is weakly lower semi-continuous, if and only if the set $U_\alpha$ is weakly sequentially closed for any $\alpha$ $\in \mathbb R$
provided that it is non-empty.

$U_\alpha := \{w ∈ X : J(w) ≤ \alpha\}$

---

I am confused on how to use the definitions to proceed.

A functional $f : X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is weakly lower semicontinuous on X if for all $x \in X$ and every sequence $x_n → x$ which
converges weakly to x ∈ X, we have
$$\liminf\limits_{x\rightarrow0} f(x_n) ≥ f(x)$$.

---

We need to use the following lemma:

Let $C\subset X$ be a closed and convex subset of a normed space $X$. Then C is weakly sequentially closed,
i.e. for a sequence $(u^n )_n$ in $C$ with $u^n\rightharpoonup u$ in X for $n\rightarrow \infty$ we have that $u \in C$.

and also the fact that:

Let $X$ be a Banach space. If a functional $J : X \rightarrow
\mathbb R$ is continuous and convex, then $U_\alpha$
is weakly sequentially closed for any $\alpha \in
\mathbb R$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $J$ is weakly lower semi-continuous on $X$, that is, according to your definition, for all $x \in X$ and every sequence $x_n \rightharpoonup x$  we have $$ \liminf\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty} J(x_n) \geq J(x).$$

Suppose $U_\alpha \neq \emptyset$. Given a sequence $(x_n)\in U_\alpha^\mathbb{N} $, we have $ \alpha \geq J(x_n)$, and by w.l.s.c., $$\alpha \geq  \liminf\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty} J(x_n) \geq J(x),$$ therefore $x\in U_\alpha$ so  $U_\alpha$ is weakly sequentially closed.

Conversely given a sequence  $(x_n)\in X$  with  $x_n \rightharpoonup x$. Consider the sequence $(J(x_n))\in\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$.

By definition, $$\liminf \limits_{n\rightarrow\infty} J(x_n) = \lim \limits_{N\rightarrow\infty} \inf\limits_{n \geq N} J(x_n).$$
Let us suppose first $\liminf \limits_{n\rightarrow\infty} J(x_n)$ is finite,
$$\liminf \limits_{n\rightarrow\infty} J(x_n) =\alpha \in \mathbb{R}.$$

Choose $\epsilon>0$ (thanks @ammath). Then for every $n\in \mathbb{N}$, since the sequence $\inf\limits_{n \geq N} J(x_n)$ is monotone increasing (the sets on which the infimum is taken are nested), a subsequence ($x_{\sigma(n)}$) satisfies $J(x_{\sigma(n)})\leq \alpha +\epsilon$, so $x_n\in U_{\alpha+\epsilon}$ (as the weak limit of the subsequence is the weak limit of the sequence). If $U_{\alpha+\epsilon}$ is weakly sequentially closed then $x\in U_{\alpha+\epsilon}$. , which means $$ \epsilon+\liminf \limits_{n\rightarrow\infty} J(x_n)=\epsilon +  \alpha \geq J(x).$$
Passing to the limit as $\epsilon\to0$, we have obtained
$$
\liminf \limits_{n\rightarrow\infty} J(x_n)\geq J(x).
$$
Finally, let us discuss the $\liminf \limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}J(x_n)=-\infty$ issue (thanks @daw below). By assumption, $J(x)\in \mathbb{R}$. Take $\alpha = J(x)-1$. A subsequence $(x_{\sigma(n)})$ is in $ U_{\alpha}$. Therefore $x\in U_{\alpha}$, that is, $J(x)\leq J(x)-1$ which doesn't happen.

Comment: If lim inf is infinite, then $J(x)=-\infty$ is a contradiction since $J(x)\in \mathbb R$. So this case cannot happen.

Comment: @daw thanks, corrected.

Comment: The solution is false. What if, for example, $J(x_n) = \frac 1n$? Then $\alpha = 0$ and you won't get your subsequence with $J(x_{\sigma(n)})\le\alpha$.

Comment: @amsmath. Thanks.